# how to prevent page reload or page refresh after clicking jquery dialog close button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

while closing dialog the whole page gets refresh. How can i avoid? Please see my code below:

```
// delete button  
<a id="confirmDelete" class="button orange" href="#"     onclick="goDelete(this);">Delete</a>  

// function goDelete that opens a dialog.  
function goDelete(a) {
    var id = a.closest("[data-id]").getAttribute("data-id");
    var url = window.location.origin + "/nurse_notes/delete_confirm.jsf?visitId=" + id;
    //Create a Div, then append a new iframe inside of it
    var dialog = $('<div>').append($('<iframe>').attr('src', url).css({"height":"300","width":"500"}));
    $(dialog).dialog({
        autoOpen: true,//Means open this now
        title: "Delete Confirmation",
        width: 550,
        height: 375,
        modal: true,
        position: {my: "center", at: "center",of: "body"}
    });
}
```

The problem is, when i click on Delete or cancel buttons within the dialog box, it refreshes the page. How do i stop the page refresh here?

***HTML***
Cancel
I am doing something like this but it still refreshing the page :(

I am very new to jquery, looking for input/feedback as to where i am going wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suspect something is generating an error, please check your console. Also this is not a very full example. Overall seems like heavy overkill for a delete confirmation dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a potential way to work this.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6ty8hj99/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li data-id="1">Item 1 <a id="confDel-1" class="button orange" href="#">Delete</a></li>
  <li data-id="2">Item 2 <a id="confDel-2" class="button orange" href="#">Delete</a></li>
  <li data-id="3">Item 3 <a id="confDel-3" class="button orange" href="#">Delete</a></li>
  <li data-id="4">Item 4 <a id="confDel-4" class="button orange" href="#">Delete</a></li>
  <li data-id="5">Item 5 <a id="confDel-5" class="button orange" href="#">Delete</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function goDelete(a) {
  var id = $(a).parent().data("id");
  var url = var url = window.location.origin + "/nurse_notes/delete_confirm.jsf?visitId=" + id;
  console.log("Delete Confirm: " + url);

  var $diag = $("<div>").dialog({
    modal: true,
    width: 550,
    height: 375,
    title: "Delete Confirmation",
    position: {
      of: "body"
    },
    close: function() {
      $(this).dialog("destroy");
    }
  });
  var $frame = $("<iframe>").attr("src", url).css({
    width: 500,
    height: 300
  });
  $diag.append($frame);
}

$(function() {
  $(".button").button();
  $("a[id^='confDel']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Click Event triggered by #" + $(this).attr("id"));
    goDelete(this);
  });
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So now when i click on X at the top right of the dialog, it does refreshes the page. But when i click on Delete or cancel buttons within the dialog box, it refreshes the page. How do i stop the page refresh here? Also

Comment: Thank you for your response. So now when i click on X at the top right of the dialog, it does not refreshes the page. But when i click on Delete or cancel buttons within the dialog box, it refreshes the page. How do i stop the page refresh here? 
***HTML***
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Cancel</a>
I am doing something like this but it still refreshing the page :(

Comment: @Vandana I suspect that this is due to javascript code that is not being added to the DOM or is having some other issue. Since the content is being loaded via  an `iframe` it makes it hard to know. Are the Delete and Cancel buttons generated in your current code or generated by the MVC page?